# Given a span of linearly dependent vectors, how do you find a set of linearly independent vectors which span the same set?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let's say we have linearly dependent vectors $v_1, \dots , v_n$ , and we consider $\operatorname{Span}\{v_1, \dots , v_n\}$. Let's say we want to find a linearly independent set of vectors which span the same set.

If we put the vectors into a matrix, perform Gaussian elimination, and choose the vectors corresponding to the pivot columns, would we then have a set of linearly independent vectors which span the same set?

Comment: Yes.  You would.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that operating on the rows of a matrix $ A $ amounts to multiply $ A $ on the left by an elementary matrix (i.e., a matrix obtained by operating on the rows of the identity matrix).

Now, given a vector $ x $ and an invertible matrix $ P $, the product $ Px $ gives the coordinates of the vector $ x $ in another base (up to you to find which).

Summing up, when you row-operate on $ A $ what you're really doing is transforming the column vectors that make up $ A $ into another (more suitable) base. This is why the procedure you described works.

I'm sure your question have been answered multiple times here.

P.S. Please observe that
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & \dots & a_{1n}\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
a_{m1} & \dots & a_{mn}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\
\vdots\\
x_n
\end{pmatrix}=
x_1\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11}\\
\vdots\\
a_{m1}
\end{pmatrix} +\dots +
x_n \begin{pmatrix}
a_{1n}\\
\vdots\\
a_{mn}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
p_{11} & \dots & p_{1m}\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
p_{m1} & \dots & p_{mm}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & \dots & a_{1n}\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
a_{m1} & \dots & a_{mn}
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
p_{11} & \dots & p_{1m}\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
p_{m1} & \dots & p_{mm}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
b_{11}\\
\vdots\\
b_{m1}
\end{pmatrix}
& \dots &
\begin{pmatrix}
p_{11} & \dots & p_{1m}\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
p_{m1} & \dots & p_{mm}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
b_{1n}\\
\vdots\\
b_{mn}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
for any vector $ x $ and matrices $ A $ and $ P $.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I understand why swapping rows or multiplying a row by a scalar is a change of basis, but I don't understand how adding rows is a change of basis. Do you know why this is the case? 

And yeah. Someone probably has asked this before. I just couldn't find a quick replica.

Comment: The change of basis matrix from the basis $ \mathscr E $ to $ \mathscr E^\prime $ is the inverse of the matrix $ \alpha_{\mathscr E^\prime,\mathscr E} $ having for columns the coordinates of the vectors $e_i^\prime\in \mathscr E^\prime$ with respect to the basis $ \mathscr E $, since
$$
\alpha_{\mathscr E,\mathscr E^\prime}=\alpha_{\mathscr E^\prime,\mathscr E}\text{.}
$$
and
$$
\alpha_{\mathscr E^\prime}(x)=\alpha_{\mathscr E,\mathscr E^\prime}\alpha_{\mathscr E}(x)
$$
where $ \alpha_{\mathscr E}(x) $ is the coordinate tuple of $ x $ in the basis $\mathscr E$, for every vector $ x $.

Comment: There's a typo in the previous comment: it's
$$
\alpha_{\mathscr E,\mathscr E^\prime}=(\alpha_{\mathscr E^\prime,\mathscr E})^{-1}\text{.}
$$
and not what I wrote.

Comment: So, let's take an invertible matrix $ P $ and suppose we want to see $ P $ as the change of basis from the standard basis $ \mathscr E $ to another base $  \mathscr E^\prime $. We look at $ P $ as if $ P = \alpha_{\mathscr E,\mathscr E^\prime} $, i.e., we look at the columns of $ P $ as if they contain the coordinates of the vectors of the new basis $ \mathscr E $ with respect to $ \mathscr E^\prime $. But we want the coordinates of the $ e_j\in \mathscr E^\prime $ *with respect to $ \mathscr E $*! So what do we do?

Comment: Thanks for your responses, and sorry for the late reply! If I'm being honest, I don't really understand what you're saying. I appreciate your effort and enthusiasm nonetheless! :)